# How do I generate a Kotlin test for my Kotlin file in IntelliJ Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

`Navigate -> Test`, or `Ctrl+Shift+T` (`Shift+⌘+T` on Mac) always creates a Java test class, even for a `.kt` file. How do I tell Android Studio to generate a Kotlin test class instead?

Comment: What is the version of your Android Studio?

Comment: It should generate a Kotlin file for a Kotlin class. I tested this with Kotlin plugin 1.3.70, AS 3.6.1. If it doesn't work for you, please create an issue at http://kotl.in/issue with steps to reproduce and a sample project, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! They helped finding the problem: I added Kotlin code to my JUnit4 test file template, and that broke the conversion process, leaving me with a Java test class containing Kotlin code.